# How to add symbols to prettify and pretty modes?

Tags: prettify-symbols-mode, proof-general

I am trying to configure Emacs with ProofGeneral (the Coq IDE) to display mathematical symbols in place of the abbreviations `->`, `=>`, `forall` and `exists`.

My current `.emacs` script is as follows:

```
;; Open .v files with Proof General's Coq mode

(load "~/.emacs.d/lisp/PG/generic/proof-site")

;; Load pretty-mode script

(load "~/.emacs.d/lisp/pretty-mode")

;; Coq symbols

(add-hook 'coq-mode-hook
      (lambda ()
        (mapc (lambda (pair) (push pair prettify-symbols-alist))
            '(("forall". x2200)
              ("->". x2190)
              ("exists". x2203)
              ("=>". x21D2)))))
```

following examples found [here](http://www.dougwoos.com/2014/03/01/prettifying-coq-buffers-in-emacs.html) and [here](http://www.modernemacs.com/post/prettify-mode/).

When I enter `coq-mode` and enable either or both of `global-pretty-mode` and `global-prettify-symbols-mode`, I see no change. I only manage to get a Greek `lambda` in `lisp-mode` and `python-mode`.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: `x2200` is a symbol with a funny name.  Instead you should have a character there.  It could be `?∀` or it could be `#x2200` or `?\u2200`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Stefan for your reply, that solved my issue.

For completeness, I'm posting my full .emacs file in case anybody else is looking to achieve similar formatting results in ProofGeneral:

```
;; Open .v files with Proof General's Coq mode

(load "~/.emacs.d/lisp/PG/generic/proof-site")

;; Coq symbols

(global-prettify-symbols-mode 1)

(setq coq-symbols-list '(lambda ()
        (mapc (lambda (pair) (push pair prettify-symbols-alist))
            '(("forall". ?∀)
              ("exists". ?∃)
              ("~" . ?¬)
              ("/\\" . ?⋀)
              ("\\/" . ?⋁)
              ("=>". ?⇒)
              ("->". ?→)
              ("<-" . ?←)
              ("<->" . ?↔)
              ("nat" . ?ℕ)
              ("*" . ?×)))))

;; Prettify Coq script editor

(add-hook 'coq-mode-hook coq-symbols-list)

;; Prettify Coq output in proofs
(add-hook 'coq-goals-mode-hook coq-symbols-list)
```

Comment: Couple of code suggestions: 1) don't quote lambdas; 2) you can just `append` your alist to `prettify-symbols-alist` in one go instead of calling a function for each pair